# apache Rewrite rule appends /html directory for no reason

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a domain `foo.tech`.

I want to use a new domain `footech.io` instead.

The redirect also has to make sure all the URLs work.

E.g `foo.tech/bar` goes to `footech.io/bar`

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.tech [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://footech.io/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For some reason, it decides to add `/html` at the end of my domain.

So now if I visit `foo.tech` it will redirect to `footech.io/html`

If I visit `foo.tech/bar` it will redirect to `footech.io/html/bar`

Please help.

Update:

I think the `/html` comes from the `$1`

I've tried to make the rewrite rule as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://footech.io/$1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

going to `foo.tech` leads to `footech.io/html//html/`

going to `foo.tech/bar` leads to `footech.io/html/bar/html/bar`

final update:
I made it work now using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.tech [NC]
RewriteRule ^html/(.*) http://footech.io/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I did clear browser cache, not sure about which rule you are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fix it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.tech [NC]
RewriteRule ^html/(.*) http://footech.io/$1 [R=301,L]
```